# Testing Google Maps API with Mocha in React

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, testing, mocha.js, chai

I would like to write tests for the Google Maps API using Mocha and Chai in React.

How would I go about writing a test for the following features?

1. When I hover over a div, the map's center should change.
2. When I hover over another div, a special icon should appear on the map.

Again, I am only looking to implement tests for these features. I know it is not the proper order to do it, but I already wrote functioning code for all of them ;)

Comment: test on hover if the hover function is called.